How to apply anonymous function over variables in R data.table?
I have a set of data tables (via data.table) in R and am trying to apply an anonymous function over a set of names variables over this set of data tables. I don't think iterating over data tables is the problem, but my syntax for applying an anonymous function over variables. I'll also note that I am using version [1.15.4] of data.table.
There are two variables in each data table that have numerical values (age-range numbers), some of which are -1 and 99. These represent NAs and I am trying to change them to NAs. I am not so sure about the syntax to do this. Below, I show syntax based on one data.table vignette (https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-reference-semantics.html): flights[, names(.SD) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = is.character] and another way that also doesn't work. Below is a reproducible example. I'm not sure of the conventions for including multiple attempts, so I've included the code section separately below for my other attempt.
library(data.table)

# Creating two data tables with ID, fiscal year, 
  # and two variables ("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end")
  # that I am trying to map an anonymous function on below

# Notice that for some values of "age_at_fy_start" and 
  # "age_at_fy_end", they are -1 or 99. These represent 
  # NAs and I need to convert them to NA across both variables

df1 <- data.table(
  id = 1:5, 
  fy = rep(2000, 5),
  age_at_fy_start = c(3, -1, 4, 99, 10), 
  age_at_fy_end = c(-1, 12, 5, 10, 99)
)

df2 <- data.table(
  id = 1:5, 
  fy = rep(2001, 5), 
  age_at_fy_start = c(-1, 13, 5, 99, 11), 
  age_at_fy_end = c(4, -1, 99, 10, 11)
)

# In larger context, I am doing many operations on a set
  # of data tables (like `df1` and `df2`). I am focusing 
  # just on this specific operation below. 

# iterating over data tables by getting number from 
  # naming convention
for (each in 1:2) {
  
  # defining name of data table based on iterating number
    # `df1` `df2`
  df_name <- paste0("df", each)

  # and getting each object from global environment
  df <- get(df_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  # ensuring that data frame is data table format   
    # for data.table syntax to work
  df <- as.data.table(df)


  ### Section I'm asking about here: 
  
  # now I am lapply-ing the anonymous function to 
    # convert values of -1 and 99 across both variables 
    # to NA
  df[, names(.SD) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(
    x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x)),
    .SDcols = c("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end")]

  ###

  # assigning current iteration data table to global
    # environment with corresponding name 
    # with "_new" just to keep original data present
  assign(paste0(df_name, "_new"), df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  # removing as the modified data has been saved
  rm(df)
  
}
#> Error: LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')

# more cleaning up after loop completion
rm(each, df_name)

# now I am lapply-ing the anonymous function to 
  # convert values of -1 and 99 across both variables 
  # to NA
df[, c("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end") := 
    lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x))]
  
#> Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(c("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end"), : 
#> Supplied 2 columns to be assigned 4 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.


Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0

I know that this doesn't answer your exact question, but it is common that data input methods allow for the user to specify what should be treated as NA. For example, the fread function has the argument na.strings which you can modify to include -1 and 99. This would mean that they're automatically converted on input instead of you having to convert them later.

You may want to store them in a variable.
> cols <- c("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end")
> df1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x)), .SDcols=cols]
> df1
      id    fy age_at_fy_start age_at_fy_end
   <int> <num>           <num>         <num>
1:     1  2000               3            NA
2:     2  2000              NA            12
3:     3  2000               4             5
4:     4  2000              NA            10
5:     5  2000              10            NA

For multiple data frames you can search by pattern in an mget(ls()) approach (note the envir= argument in both functions which defaults to current) and use lapply which will change both data frames in place. The invisible() just omits console output, you may keep it.
> lapply(mget(ls(pattern='df\\d')), \(df) {
+   df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(x %in% c(-1, 99), NA, x)), .SDcols=cols]
+ }) |> invisible()


One possible way to solve your problem:
cols = c("age_at_fy_start", "age_at_fy_end")

for(df in mget(ls(pattern='df\\d'))) for(cl in cols) {
  set(df, i=which(df[[cl]] %in% c(-1, 99)), j=cl, value=NA)
}

rm(df, cl)


df1
      id    fy age_at_fy_start age_at_fy_end
   <int> <num>           <num>         <num>
1:     1  2000               3            NA
2:     2  2000              NA            12
3:     3  2000               4             5
4:     4  2000              NA            10
5:     5  2000              10            NA

df2
      id    fy age_at_fy_start age_at_fy_end
   <int> <num>           <num>         <num>
1:     1  2001              NA             4
2:     2  2001              13            NA
3:     3  2001               5            NA
4:     4  2001              NA            10
5:     5  2001              11            11

